# If $xy^T$ is symmetric then $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

I am working on matrices over $\mathbb Z_n$. And I need to show that $xy^T$ is symmetric if and only if $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent. The other direction can be easily verified. However, I find it difficult to prove that if $xy^T$ is symmetric then $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 9):

If $xy^T$ is symmetric we have that $xy^T = yx^T$. Now apply both sides to an arbitary vector $v$ such that $x^Tv \neq 0$:

$$xy^Tv = yx^Tv \to \lambda_1 x = \lambda_2 y$$

Hence the vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: notice that we are not on an integer domain.. $\lambda_2$ can still be zero

Comment: @Exodd does the fix work?

Comment: Actually that was my first attempt to prove it however I cannot guarantee that $y^Tx$ or $x^Tx$ is not equal to zero.

Comment: yep, it works now, since either $x=0$ or it has a non-zero entry, so you can take $v=e_i$

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Helped a lot.